# Convert raw class object to specific class object

Tags: java, hibernate

I am working on Hibernate and Spring
I designed a method that return type is List.
When I am querying to database using hibernate it create specific type of object.
I want to iterate list of raw type object and print the object property.

Here I attached my method

```
public List getAnalyticsbyid(String userId)
{
    Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
    String querystring="SELECT DISTINCT bounces ,visits, landingPagePath  FROM AnalyticsDataFeedBean where userId='"+userId+"' ORDER BY bounces DESC";
    Query query=session.createQuery(querystring).addEntity(AnalyticsDataFeedBean.class);
    query.setMaxResults(10);
    return query.list();
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? Return a List<Object[]> rather than a List? Or transform each Object[] in the list into an instance of one of your classes? What difficulty do you have?

Answer (score 1):

Your HQL query returns `List<Object[]>` you can change the method signature to

```
public List<Object[]> getAnalyticsbyid(String userId)
```

And in the place where this method is called iterate through the list and print the details

```
List<Object[]> list = getAnalyticsbyid("user");
for (Object[] objects : list) {
    for (Object object : objects) {
        System.out.print(object);
        System.out.print("\t");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

If you want to display it as a table in a `jsp` file start with following snippet

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <th>bounces</th>
            <th>visits</th>
            <th>landingPagePath</th>
        </tr>

    <c:forEach items="${analytics}" var="objects">
        <tr>
            <c:forEach items="${objects}" var="object">
                <td><c:out value="${object}"/></td>
            </c:forEach>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Comment: Its return list<Object> and object class contain three field that is based on the query.Based on the query its creating object that fields are select field in query

Comment: This method is called controlled and the list what we are  getting i want to iterate in jsp using jstl tag

Comment: List list=analyticsDAO.getAnalyticsbyid(Integer.toString(user.getId()));

Comment: modelView.addObject("analytics",list);
  return modelView; Sorry that is controller coding

Comment: <c:forEach items="${analytics}" var="a">
 <tr>
 <td>${a}</td>
 
 </tr>
 </c:forEach>  In this place i want to iterate arraylist and object a contain three filed value i want to print three field value in jsp page

Comment: Problem is that i dont know arraylist which type of object contain and i want to get field value of that object.

Comment: I solved that problem, the list type is Object[] and I get the list of Object[] and that ObjectArray i put value to bean and add to arrayList and iterated to jsp page